# Can this function structure slow the application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I was reading some code on the internet and I saw a peculiar function component structure, also you can use react hooks there. Code example:

```
export default function Payment() {

  const doPayment = async () => {
     ...//logic
     return value;
  }

  const doPayment2 = async () => {
    ...//logic
    return value;
  }

  return {
    doPayment,
    doPayment2
  }
}
```

And you can import it in this way:

```
import payment from '../../helpers/payment';

export default function Screen() {
  
  const { doPayment, doPayment2 } = payment();
  
  ...
}
```

Imagine a file with 1000 lines, I wonder if this can slow down the app, cause it will be re-created at every react render.

Comment: What makes you think it's a react component? The pathname containing "helpers" suggests to me that is exactly what this is, helper functions

Comment: I didn't said that it's a react component, just a component. Maybe it's not the right term, but as you instantiate it on `payment()` I thought that we could call it a component. Also we can use react hooks inside of it.

Comment: it is not recreating the import, but u still load the complete function with is sub functions. If you want to optimize it,  search for "tree-shaking"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Screen is a React component...

> Imagine a file with 1000 lines, I wonder if this can slow down the app, cause it will be re-created at every react render.

It *could*, but in practical terms, it's not very likely to. In *most* given segments of code, performance is a complete non-issue - rather, if low performance is really an issue, the better approach is to run an actual profiling test to see what's taking up the most CPU time, allowing you to identify the **few** bottlenecks that are causing the slowdown, and then fix *those*. This section you're looking at here probably isn't one of them - but it's not impossible.

If this portion of code *was* causing the problem, you could fix it by memoizing the return value:

```
const { doPayment, doPayment2 } = useMemo(payment, []);
```

If the situation warrants it, you could even lift it out of the component completely:

```
import payment from '../../helpers/payment';

const { doPayment, doPayment2 } = payment();
export default function Screen() {
  ...
}
```

Or pass it down as a static prop.

Comment: Since OP mentions hooks: I just want to mention that these optimizations no longer allow allow using hooks inside of `payment`. Because hooks have to be called on every single render; all of them and always in the same order.